# How to get Pinia store inside the Vue3 plugin?

Tags: plugins, vuejs3, store

I need to create Vue3 plugin and want to use Pinia store inside the plugin. But dont know how to get store instance inside the plugin. The plugin looks like:

```
export default {
    install: (app) => {
        console.log(app)
        // inject a globally available $translate() method
        app.config.globalProperties.$translate = (translations, key) => {

            let result = translations[key] ? translations[key][0] : ''  // First item as default value or ''

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Can I find it in app abject and use it insid the translate function?

Answer (score 0):

The solution looks like this
import { useAppStore } from '@/store/app'

```
export default {
    install: (app) => {

        const appStore = useAppStore()  // This is crucial 

        app.config.globalProperties.$translate = (translations, key) => {

            const translation = translations.find((item, key) => {
                if ( item[key] && item[key].locale == appStore.defaultLang.val ) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return translation ? translation : defaultTranslation
        }
    }
}
```